# Selecting options with undetected_chromedriver in a drop down list

Tags: python, pandas, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

i'm trying to use send_keys with a drop down list with undetected_chrome driver, in my other code section just do it with selenium, but with my scraper bot was being target for cloudflare, so i turn on to undetected,

as we can see bellow, i find the element with undetected/pandas and click:

```
df.iloc[323].se_click()
```

after this i need to scroll down the options or just arrow down, but i can't.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ba6B.png)

because, if type this code isnt work:

```
df.iloc[323].se_send_keys(Key.ARROW_DOWN)
```

People who can help me with a way to use send_keys in a drop down list

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i need to select an information in a drop down list, but i cant with iloc, how can i do this?